# Add flush() into Object serialization

Tags: java

I have this serialization and deserialization classes which I use to send objects into Kafka:

```
public class SaleRequestFactorySerializer implements Serializable, Serializer<SaleRequestFactory> {

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, SaleRequestFactory data)
    {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try
        {
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
            outputStream.writeObject(data);
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return out.toByteArray();
    }
}

public class SaleResponseFactoryDeserializer implements Serializable, Deserializer<SaleRequestFactory> {

    @Override
    public SaleRequestFactory deserialize(String topic, byte[] data)
    {
        SaleRequestFactory saleRequestFactory = null;
        try
        {
            ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
            ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
            saleRequestFactory = (SaleRequestFactory) in.readObject();
            in.close();
        }
        catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return saleRequestFactory;
    }
}
```

It's not clear for me do I need to add `flush()` methods in order to prevent memory leak. Can you guide me what I'm missing into my code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the the API docs of `ByteArray<IO>Stream` say that you don't need to.  Pleas check the documentation.

Comment: Is there something into the code that I can improve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to; the garbage collector doesn't magically get confused by resources. It's that the resource they represent may take years to close if the GC never even kicks in because there's no need for it. There's no 'leaking' whatsoever for these.

BAIS, BAOS, OIS, OOS, etc - these don't actually represent any OS resources. Contrast to e.g. `FileInputStream`, `Files.newInputStream`, `socket.getInputStream()`, etc.

Regardless of whether it represents a resource or not, closing any stream will flush as part of the operation.

You can improve this code considerably by ditching OIS and OOS; you can do some web searching to find that almost everybody, notably including most of the java language designers over at oracle itself, don't particularly like java's built-in serialization. The protocol is tightly bound up with java (so, it's not possible to document the scheme without saying: "Well, uh, take this class file, load up a JVM, deserialize it there, otherwise, no way to read this thing", which is not great. It's also not a particularly efficient algorithm, and produces rather large blobs of binary data. Look instead into serialization schemes which don't use java's built in mechanism, such as Jackson or GSON, which serialize objects into JSON and back out. JSON isn't an efficient format either, but at least it's easy to read with eyeballs, or from other languages, and it is easily specced.

If you want as much performance as you can squeeze out, write a [protobuf](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers) based serializer.

If you want to stick with this code instead, note that `e.printStackTrace()` is the *worst* way to handle an exception. An exception happened - your choice is to dump part of the error into `System.err`, beyond the reach of loggers and completely invisible on most server deployments, the rest into the void, and then **keep on going** like nothing went wrong, returning empty byte arrays, most likely causing either wild goose chases (with your app 'silently doing nothing', and you wondering what's going on), or a cascade of errors (Where the weird state you're returning, such as empty arrays, causes other errors, which, if you handle them the same way, cause still other errors, resulting in  a single problem sending a flurry of hundreds of cascading stack traces to syserr, all of them except the first utterly irrelevant). It also means you have to dirty up your code - for example, you tend to run into an issue where the compiler demands you initialize a variable before using it - even though you always set that variable, unless exceptions occur.

The right way to handle an exception is to actually handle it (and logging it is not handling it). If that's not an option, then the right way is to throw an exception. Give callers a chance. If you can't throw the exception straight onwards, wrap it. If you can't do that, wrap it in a runtimeexception. Thus, the ¯\*(ツ)*/¯ I have no clue and I don't want to be bothered line of code is not `e.printStackTrace()` but `throw new RuntimeException("Unhandled", e);` - this has none of these problems: It lists ALL the info about the error, it will not cause execution to continue with weird data returned, and log frameworks have a chance to see this stuff.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any other good practice that I can apply?

Comment: As a general rule? No. The above is it.